# Solr connection from private network

Tags: linux, authentication, solr, jetty, port

I have Solr 5.2.1 running under Jetty on a Linux Server and the application that connects to Solr is running on another server in the same network at Rackspace. I've closed port 8983 on the Solr server to block public access to the Solr Admin, but that means the application cannot connect to Solr.

I've tried using the private network that runs between the two servers, but have not found any way to connect the application to Solr this way without direct access to port 8983.

While I know little about Jetty, I've tried to find a solution there, or reconfiguring localhost, but no success.

Sorry but I don't have any real examples to provide, as I've been casting about in the dark for a solution as I know very little about connecting server to server.

Any helpful advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: may be , you can only change solr port  use -p param , but it still public , if you want to control solr admin access permission, i think use linux iptables  is better choice .

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for the replies. In fact the solution was to construct a reverse proxy. I did not know about proxies when I wrote the question. It would have been more easy to understand. The best solution for (at least for me) was from here:

https://github.com/o19s/solr_nginx

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the infrastructure at RackSpace, I suspect that all machines are considered "public" and not behind a firewall, or protected with [non-routable IP addresses](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html).

Like @Qin-Dong-Liang pointed out, the the most you have to control Jetty is the host (interface that it listens on), and the port.

So that means, the moment you setup a listening port on anything but `localhost` is the moment that all machines can access that server.

If you need to restrict what machines are allowed to connect to that host:port combination, then you should look into doing that with lower level tools on the OS of your solr server.  Tools like iptables, ipfw, etc.